# Is it possible to reinterpret an object reference as native int using c# code?

Tags: c#, unsafe, reinterpret-cast

**Disclaimer: I understand this is an unsafe operation and bad practice, I merely want to know if it's possible.**

Basically, I'm trying to convert an object reference to a `nint` (`IntPtr`). They take up the same size in memory, so it should be possible in theory. I've gotten it to work using a DynamicMethod:

```
DynamicMethod dyn = new DynamicMethod("", typeof(nint), new[] { typeof(object) });
ILGenerator il = dyn.GetILGenerator();
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
Func<object, nint> objectToIntFunction = (Func<object, nint>)dyn.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<object, nint>));
object obj = new object();
nint asNativeInt = objectToIntFunction(obj);
```

Is this possible using only C# code? I haven't found anything suitable in `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`.

I've also tried this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct Cast
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public nint Number;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public object Object;
};

Cast cast = new Cast
{
    Object = obj
};
nint number = cast.Number;
```

But I get the following error:

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type
> 'Cast' from assembly because it
> contains an object field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or
> overlapped by a non-object field.'

Comment: This isn't just a bad practice.  It's not useful, because the GC can move the object at any point in time to a new location.  It's only sensible to get a pointer to something that has a fixed location, and as it is that object both isn't, and can't be, pinned.

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't found anything suitable in `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`

```cs
object obj = new object();
nint asNativeInt = Unsafe.As<object, nint>(ref obj);
```

There you have it.